# Dynamically Change HTML Content Using a URL Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been struggling with dynamically changing HTML content using URL variables. Let me give you an example and than provide you my code thus far.

Ex. I have a landing page with content to be changed. I would like to have a variable in my URL www.domain.com/header=new-content

I would like to be able to rewrite the HTML to show the new header using Javascript or Jquery. Here is what I have thus far. Seems like I am missing the trigger or if/else statement.

Thank you so much!

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("header");
    element.innerHTML = "New Content";
    </script>
```

Comment: is the header a querystring or an element in your html page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, when you're dealing with URL parameters, you should place a `?` before you start defining parameters. This will result in the browser retrieving the page `www.foo.bar/` instead of `www.foo.bar/header=new-content`. Once you add the question mark, you can retrieve URL parameters using the following snippet. I retrieved this from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery).

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

In your specific case, your final code, after defining the above function, might look something like this:

```
<script>
var header = getUrlParameter('header');
document.getElementById('header').innerHTML = header;
</script>
```

This will retrieve the URL parameter `header` and change the value of the element with ID `header` to the value contained in the URL. For the URL `www.foo.bar/?header=new-content`, the element's value would be changed to `new-content`. If you want to have spaces in the variable, you can remove the URL-encoded characters (ex. %20 for space) by changing the first line in the above snippet to this:

```
var header = decodeURIComponent(getUrlParameter('header'));
```

Last minute addition: I just noticed that another answer with more-or-less the same code snippet came in while I was writing this. Whoops. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could read the url and extract the desired paramenter with a function such as:

```
function fGetUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};
```

So if you are accessing a url such as:
http://www.domain.com/?header=new-content

You could store the parameter in a variable

```
var stringHeader = fGetUrlParameter("header")
```

and modify your element html

```
 var element = document.getElementById("header");
 element.innerHTML = stringHeader;
```

Comment: Yes! thank you. I didn't even think about storing the url parameter in a variable. Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question.
Assuming that you want to pass a parameter using the URL the correct way to rewrite your url would be 
www.domain.com?header=new-content
That would make your variable named header equal the value of new-content. 
The way to extract your data would be:

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("header");
    //use your variable
 </script>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you. I missed the ? in the url.